# Dockerfile not using cache in RUN composer install command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I thought i understand Docker already, but today i found some problem about utilizing docker cache.

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM quay.io/my_company/phpjenkins

WORKDIR /usr/src/my_project
ADD composer.json composer.json
ADD composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install -o

ADD . .

RUN mkdir -p temp/unittest/cache log

RUN cp app/config/config.unittest.template.neon app/config/config.unittest.neon

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

I expect docker to use the cache until `ADD . .`

However, every build, look like docker try to do `composer install` every time.

Here is some output

```
+ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run app vendor/bin/phpunit -d memory_limit=2048M
Creating network "xxx_default" with the default driver
Creating xxx_rabbitmq_1
Creating xxx_mysql_1
Building app
Step 1/9 : FROM quay.io/my_company/phpjenkins
 ---> f10ea65fb7df
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/my_project
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 07ad76770cd2
Step 3/9 : ADD composer.json composer.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0d22314b81af
Step 4/9 : ADD composer.lock composer.lock
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3d41825efcb3
Step 5/9 : RUN composer install -o
 ---> Running in 38de5f08eb46
Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details ....
...
 ---> aa05dc9ddc5f
Removing intermediate container 581aa7e4b00f
Step 6/9 : ADD . .
 ---> 8796a9235b9a
Removing intermediate container b7354231fbd7
```

I run out of lead, what could be possible thing that dockerfile didn't use cache for `RUN composer install` command

I'm using `Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be` on Debian, if this help for investigation.

Please advise.

Comment: Your output is from the initial `docker-compose`. Do you have output for the successive attempts where the cache is not used in step 5?

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard, i'm not sure where can i get that info for u. But in step 5), it doesn't show "Using cache", doesn't it mean that it has no attempt at all ?

Comment: The Run command cache should only be invalidated if the command string "composer install -o" changed, so this shouldn't be happening: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache
if you try any other command, just for test purposes, does it match the cache?

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around you could create two Dockerfiles. One that creates an image at the point where you would like to cache. The second Dockerfile can then use the first image as its base and make modifications as required.

```
FROM quay.io/my_company/phpjenkins

WORKDIR /usr/src/my_project
ADD composer.json composer.json
ADD composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install -o

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Build this file to mycomposerimage using

```
docker build -t mycomposerimage .
```

Then second dockerfile picks up from there

```
FROM mycomposerimage
WORKDIR /usr/src/my_project
ADD . .

RUN mkdir -p temp/unittest/cache log

RUN cp app/config/config.unittest.template.neon app/config/config.unittest.neon

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```